# Master/detail using the admin in django

Tags: django, admin, master-detail

I've googled and looked at the docs, but haven't found anything
related to this scenario:

I got a master/detail model, defined like so:

```
class Master(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   def details_url(self):
       return '<a href="here comes the url linking to details">Details</a>'
   details_url.short_description = 'Link to details'
   details_url.allow_tags = True

class Detail(models.Model):
    master = models.ForeignKey(Master)
    details = models.TextField()
```

They're exposed in the admin using admin.py. My question is this:

1) How can I make the details_url property in the Master-model so that
when exposed in the admin.py a user can click it and go the listing of
details and only see details related to that instance of Master-model?

2) If this can only be done using a custom view, how do I get the view
to produce a page looking like the rest of the admin? I know I can use
the same template code as the admin, but is there a faster way to
produce for instance listings like the details in my case? Generic
views/classes?

3) Adding Master to list_filter for the detailsAdmin-class is not
possible due to the amount of Master-records. Or is it ...? And even
if it was possible, how can I set filters from another page, like if I
click a link in the change_list for Master-model going to the Details
change_list, how can I set the filtering to be set to a specific
instance of a Master model?

In short; all I want is the have the change_list filtered to only show
details related to a specific master-record and reuse as much of the
admin-code/featurebase as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Django 1.2.4, you could create filtered links to models in the admin using GET query like this: `http://your_site.com/admin/your_app/detail/?master__id__exact=2`.

But it was a bit of security hole, and got fixed. Now you'll get a `SuspiciousOperation` exception if you try to filter your models using lookup that is not specified in `list_filter` attribute.

Though there's a fix for that. [This workaround](http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/fixing-django-124s-suspiciousoperation-filtering/) implements a `valid_lookups` attribute so that you can perform filtering using some lookups via URL get query, without having these lookups exposed in the admin interface.

For this to work, you'll need to override `lookup_allowed()` method on your ModelAdmin. Here is the example code, check the post mentioned above for details.

```
class DetailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    valid_lookups = ()
    def lookup_allowed(self, lookup, *args, **kwargs):
        if lookup.startswith(self.valid_lookups):
            return True
         return super(DetailAdmin, self).lookup_allowed(lookup, *args, **kwargs)
```